# Can't find RCTPushNotification.xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-push-notifications, node-modules, react-native-push-notification

I'd like to use the file `RCTPushNotification.xcodeproj` inside the directory `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS`, to add it in my Libraries folder in order to manage iOS push notifications. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/react-native-push-notifications-ios-android/.

The problem is that I can't find it, even after deleting `node_modules` and executing `npm install && react-native link`.

Here is my `package.json` dependencies, but I don't think that a package could modify my directory:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view": "^1.0.14",
    "firebase": "^6.5.0",
    "pubnub": "^4.27.0",
    "pubnub-react": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-optimized-flatlist": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.11.2"
  }
```

Here are the only files I can see on this directory:

- `NativePushNotificationManager.js`
- `RCTPushNotificationManager.h`
- `RCTPushNotificationManager.m`
- `React-RCTPushNotification.podspec`

Knowing that `RCTPushNotificationManager.m` and `RCTPushNotificationManager.h` should be inside my xCode project, I tried to put the entire `PushNotificationIOS` folder in my `Libraries` folder, but it doesn't seems to work because there is not the necessary `Products` folder inside of an xCode project.

I also tried to put each of this files in my `Libraries` folder, but Xcode doesn't consider them as xCode projects (not very surprising).

This issue doesn't seem to have been encountered earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After just spending a lot of time and effort on push notifications, I recommend you look into OneSignal push notifications. Saved me a lot of time. 
However, you should be able to find the .xcodeproj here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios/tree/master/ios

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this file is not compatible with the next steps proposed by the tutorial. I'll try OneSignal !

Comment: For me, OneSignal is as complicated as Pubnub. I already did the android part, I prefer finish the iOS part with the same technology.

Comment: I withdraw what I said. OneSignal is great ! Thank you !

Comment: Hey,
I am also getting this issue, Please help me how to fix it.